# How to skip unwanted text with attoparsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, attoparsec

I'd like to parse E-Mails similar to this

```
Random Info: ........
From: email@domain.com
Other Info: .......
Subject: ima subject
Some More Info: .....

This is a message.
```

But I don't need all the information from this E-Mail. Only "From", "Subject" and the message itself. How can I parse a message like this? More specifically how can I skip the unwanted data?

Here is the code I have so far

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module MailParser where

import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.Attoparsec.Text

type From    = Address
type Message = T.Text
type Subject = T.Text
type Local   = T.Text
type Domain  = T.Text

data Address = Address Local Domain
data Mail = Mail From Subject Message

addressParser :: Parser Address
addressParser = do
    _ <- string "From: "
    local  <- takeWhile1 (/= '@')
    _ <- char '@'
    domain <- takeWhile1 (/= '\n')
    return $ Address local domain

subjectParser :: Parser T.Text
subjectParser = do
    _ <- string "Subject: "
    takeWhile1 (/= '\n')

messageParser :: Parser Message
messageParser = do
    _ <- char '\n'
    takeText

mailParser :: Parser Mail
mailParser = do
    -- skip unwanted info
    from <- addressParser
    -- skip unwanted info
    subject <- subjectParser
    -- skip unwanted info
    message <- messageParser
    return $ Mail from subject message
```

Comment: Note that instead of writing `_ <- foo` you can always write just `foo`.

Comment: I know but I get warnings in Atom about that and I don't know how to turn them off.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ignoring text with the parser, another approach is to parse the email normally and then project only the headers you are interested in.

```
-- After parsing, say we end up with this data.
data Email = Email { headers :: [Header], message :: Text }

data Header = Header { label :: Text, value :: Text }

-- Helper to find headers in an Email.
findHeader :: Text -> Email -> Maybe Header
findHeader x = find ((==x) . label) . headers

-- Project the Email's "Subject" header.
subject :: Email -> Maybe Header
subject = findHeader "Subject"

-- Project the Email's "From" header.
from :: Email -> Maybe Header
from = findHeader "From"
```

Also, [hsemail](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsemail) and [hsemail-ns](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsemail-ns) have defined Parsec email parsers.